# Datatables Column visibility not working when there are more columns than can be visible at current size

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I have a table that has at least 15 columns, but at the current size it only hows 8 columns, which is fine.

Now, when I click on column visibility and hide a currently shown column, the expected behaviour is that a column that is hidden but set to be visible pops into the table (as a new space is available as I have hidden a column).

This does not happen, and instead the current columns width increases. Even if I hide all columns but one, that one column will get the width of the table.

Here is my datatables config:

```
   this._table.DataTable({
        stateSave: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: this._url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: (data) => {
                data.csrf = csrfToken
            }
        },
        pageLength: 50,
        columns: this._columns,
        colReorder: true,
        order: order,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                columns: ':not(.entity-hyperlink)'
            },
            jQuery.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                extend: 'copyHtml5'
            }),
            jQuery.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                extend: 'csvHtml5'
            }),
            jQuery.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                extend: 'excelHtml5'
            }),
            jQuery.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'A1'
            }),
        ]
    });
```

Comment: You need to give your `columns` a `width` ...

Comment: Looks like by downgrading `datatables.net-responsive-bs` to `2.2.0` made the trick!

Comment: Sounds strange :) If you answer your own question with an example / explanation, I will be happy to support it.